# Does the DGK Color Tools DKK chart have defined color values?

Tags: color-management

Does the DGK Color Tools DKK chart have defined color values, in either RGB or some other color space? I notice more attention has been paid to the Macbeth ColorChecker chart.

Answer (score 2):

It's written on the back of the chart.